# How to avoid div hitting each other after JQuery expansion

Tags: jquery, html, css

Before expanding a div, the div are separated from each other.
When I press the "SCOPRI DI PIÙ" button to expand a div, the div hit each other, but I don't want the div to do this.

How can I do to solve this problem?

This is the situation before expanding the div:
[image]

This is the situation having pressed the button:
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $p = $('#more');
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $p.css('display', 'block');
        $("#show").hide();
        $("#hide").show();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $p.css('display', 'none');
        $("#show").show();
        $("#hide").hide();
    });

    var $p1 = $('#more1');
    $('#show1').click(function() {
        $p1.css('display', 'block');
        $("#show1").hide();
        $("#hide1").show();
    });

    $("#hide1").click(function() {
        $p1.css('display', 'none');
        $("#show1").show();
        $("#hide1").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#child-left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #a51c30;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    padding: 15px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#child-right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #bbbbbb;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    padding: 15px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="child-left">
            <i class="fa fa-gears" style="font-size:36px; color: #bbbbbb; margin-left: 15px;"></i>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px; color: white;">BACHECA CHALLENGES</span>
            <br>
            <p class="style">Pubblicate le vostre challenge su una bacheca accessibile a tutti i potenziali solvers e in ogni momento potrete sapere quanti utenti stanno lavorando per trovare una soluzione ai vostri problemi. Al termine della challenge verrete contattati
                dal nostro staff che si preoccuperà di mostrarvi tutte le soluzioni trovate.</p>
            <button id="show" class="btn btn-primary">Scopri di più</button>
            <p id="more" class="style" style="display: none;">
                <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis nec elit quis convallis. Sed placerat metus elit, vel gravida magna cursus sit amet. In eleifend, sem eu blandit vulputate, diam lectus tincidunt felis,
                vel posuere diam dui eget elit. Nulla tempus quis velit a ultricies. Aliquam ornare a dolor quis laoreet. Quisque et mi sapien. Pellentesque consequat neque ante, nec accumsan dolor lacinia id. Aliquam ultrices lectus gravida nibh
                sollicitudin, ac sagittis dui ullamcorper. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Quisque euismod purus vel augue tincidunt, sit amet mollis arcu sollicitudin. Nullam vitae quam risus. Nam ex turpis, posuere a aliquam ac, commodo eu magna. Aliquam
                ipsum mauris, accumsan eget mauris id, hendrerit faucibus dui. Praesent quis est non metus sagittis posuere ut et nisl.
            </p>
            <button id="hide" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none;">Nascondi</button>
        </div>

        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <div id="child-right">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:36px; color: #a51c30; margin-left: 15px;"></i>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px; color: white;">BACHECA QUESTIONS</span>
            <br>
            <p class="style" style="text-align: right;">
                Make It Happen offre un servizio di consulenza rapida ed economica: postate domande di qualunque natura e avrete <br> risposte mirate in tempi molto brevi.
            </p>
            <button id="show1" class="btn bottom_company btn-primary">Scopri di più</button>
            <p id="more1" class="style" style="display: none;">
                <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis nec elit quis convallis. Sed placerat metus elit, vel gravida magna cursus sit amet. In eleifend, sem eu blandit vulputate, diam lectus tincidunt felis,
                vel posuere diam dui eget elit. Nulla tempus quis velit a ultricies. Aliquam ornare a dolor quis laoreet. Quisque et mi sapien. Pellentesque consequat neque ante, nec accumsan dolor lacinia id. Aliquam ultrices lectus gravida nibh
                sollicitudin, ac sagittis dui ullamcorper. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Quisque euismod purus vel augue tincidunt, sit amet mollis arcu sollicitudin. Nullam vitae quam risus. Nam ex turpis, posuere a aliquam ac, commodo eu magna. Aliquam
                ipsum mauris, accumsan eget mauris id, hendrerit faucibus dui. Praesent quis est non metus sagittis posuere ut et nisl.
            </p>

            <button id="hide1" class="btn bottom_company btn-primary" style="display: none;">Nascondi</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI you should really look to DRY up your JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css property `margin-bottom: 55px!important;` to `#child-left` and `#child-right`. Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hardwit/dzxp33m0/).

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-bottom: 20px` to your css insted of `<br/>` in HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $p = $('#more');
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $p.css('display', 'block');
        $("#show").hide();
        $("#hide").show();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $p.css('display', 'none');
        $("#show").show();
        $("#hide").hide();
    });

    var $p1 = $('#more1');
    $('#show1').click(function() {
        $p1.css('display', 'block');
        $("#show1").hide();
        $("#hide1").show();
    });

    $("#hide1").click(function() {
        $p1.css('display', 'none');
        $("#show1").show();
        $("#hide1").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#child-left {

    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #a51c30;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    padding: 15px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

#child-right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #bbbbbb;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    padding: 15px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="child-left">
            <i class="fa fa-gears" style="font-size:36px; color: #bbbbbb; margin-left: 15px;"></i>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px; color: white;">BACHECA CHALLENGES</span>
            <br>
            <p class="style">Pubblicate le vostre challenge su una bacheca accessibile a tutti i potenziali solvers e in ogni momento potrete sapere quanti utenti stanno lavorando per trovare una soluzione ai vostri problemi. Al termine della challenge verrete contattati
                dal nostro staff che si preoccuperà di mostrarvi tutte le soluzioni trovate.</p>
            <button id="show" class="btn btn-primary">Scopri di più</button>
            <p id="more" class="style" style="display: none;">
                <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis nec elit quis convallis. Sed placerat metus elit, vel gravida magna cursus sit amet. In eleifend, sem eu blandit vulputate, diam lectus tincidunt felis,
                vel posuere diam dui eget elit. Nulla tempus quis velit a ultricies. Aliquam ornare a dolor quis laoreet. Quisque et mi sapien. Pellentesque consequat neque ante, nec accumsan dolor lacinia id. Aliquam ultrices lectus gravida nibh
                sollicitudin, ac sagittis dui ullamcorper. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Quisque euismod purus vel augue tincidunt, sit amet mollis arcu sollicitudin. Nullam vitae quam risus. Nam ex turpis, posuere a aliquam ac, commodo eu magna. Aliquam
                ipsum mauris, accumsan eget mauris id, hendrerit faucibus dui. Praesent quis est non metus sagittis posuere ut et nisl.
            </p>
            <button id="hide" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none;">Nascondi</button>
        </div>



        <div id="child-right">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size:36px; color: #a51c30; margin-left: 15px;"></i>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px; color: white;">BACHECA QUESTIONS</span>
            <br>
            <p class="style" style="text-align: right;">
                Make It Happen offre un servizio di consulenza rapida ed economica: postate domande di qualunque natura e avrete <br> risposte mirate in tempi molto brevi.
            </p>
            <button id="show1" class="btn bottom_company btn-primary">Scopri di più</button>
            <p id="more1" class="style" style="display: none;">
                <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis nec elit quis convallis. Sed placerat metus elit, vel gravida magna cursus sit amet. In eleifend, sem eu blandit vulputate, diam lectus tincidunt felis,
                vel posuere diam dui eget elit. Nulla tempus quis velit a ultricies. Aliquam ornare a dolor quis laoreet. Quisque et mi sapien. Pellentesque consequat neque ante, nec accumsan dolor lacinia id. Aliquam ultrices lectus gravida nibh
                sollicitudin, ac sagittis dui ullamcorper. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Quisque euismod purus vel augue tincidunt, sit amet mollis arcu sollicitudin. Nullam vitae quam risus. Nam ex turpis, posuere a aliquam ac, commodo eu magna. Aliquam
                ipsum mauris, accumsan eget mauris id, hendrerit faucibus dui. Praesent quis est non metus sagittis posuere ut et nisl.
            </p>

            <button id="hide1" class="btn bottom_company btn-primary" style="display: none;">Nascondi</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put margins in the css

```
#child-left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #a51c30;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    padding: 15px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#child-right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #bbbbbb;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    padding: 15px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```